Как обособлять придаточное предложение в составе сложносочинённого
Хотелось бы знать полное правило, как это работает, когда придаточное предложение оказывается "на стыке".
Примеры:
Он наблюдал за местом, и(,) когда из-за угла показались люди, стало очень шумно.
Бойцы сражались в полную силу, и(,) как только произошёл первый нокаут, зрители заликовали.
Я узнал, что(,) хотя он и выглядел дружелюбным, подружиться с ним было не так просто.
Мы любили ходить в кино, и(,) поскольку по утрам билеты были дешёвыми, чаще всего нас можно было встретить на самых ранних сеансах.
Всегда ли в таких случаях ставится запятая? И если нет, то когда ставится, а когда нет?

А нет для случая "на стыке" специального отдельного правила; тут и стыка-то не наблюдается.
Ага, нашла; подробности см. на скрине.

Снег выпал, и, когда наступило утро, мы пошли делать снеговика.
(Первая запятая никуда не девается, она продолжает разделять главные
предложения, вторая и третья запятые стоят на границах вклинившегося
придаточного. В этом случае мы можем безболезненно убрать
придаточное.)

Убираем скобки, обособляя придаточные.
Он наблюдал за местом, и, когда из-за угла показались люди, стало очень шумно.
Бойцы сражались в полную силу, и, как только произошёл первый нокаут, зрители заликовали.
Я узнал, что, хотя он и выглядел дружелюбным, подружиться с ним было не так просто.
Мы любили ходить в кино, и, поскольку по утрам билеты были дешёвыми, чаще всего нас можно было встретить на самых ранних сеансах.

Вот что есть о "стыке", но это не наш случай.
Стык подчинительных союзов

